# How to use sendmail on one line of command

Tags: linux

On Linux RH, how can I setup this command on one line? I cannot make a script, it's generated by a database and executed through a host command, so I cannot input multiple lines.
Thanks Pierre

```
cat <<'EOF' - test.html | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
To: nomghf@jkh.ca
Subject: hello
Content-Type: text/html
EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be equivalent in a POSIX shell:

```
{ printf '%s\n' 'To: nomghf@jkh.ca' 'Subject: hello' 'Content-Type: text/html'; cat test.html; } | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```